# Weird Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php

I have error with odd values like

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare chkconfig() (previously declared in D\x01:27)
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare chkconfig() (previously
>   declared in (\x93\x03u\xa2\x7f:27)
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare
>   chkconfig() (previously declared in \x98\xe9\xc6t\xa2\x7f:27)
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare chkconfig() (previously declared in 
>   Wut\xa2\x7f:27)
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare chkconfig() (previously declared in @.\xf7t\xa2\x7f:27)

but it is not declare in any other place.
What means that odd values?

Comment: Are you saying that the Error is lying?

Comment: no, it was working like that a long time, that problem occurs lately

Comment: these "odd values" are hex values *just say'in*

Answer (score 2):

You can just try this:

```
if (!function_exists('chkconfig')) {
    // declare your function
}
```

So that if it does exist, you won't have to redeclare it anymore.

Comment: i know, but im asking about place where it was declare. isnt  It odd that its previously declared in @.\xf7t\xa2\x7f:27 ?

Comment: Well I can't help you with that as I don't have any access to your computer.